# How do I toggle off previous class of element when a different element is clicked using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

In my pen I am using jQuery to toggle on and off css classes when buttons are clicked.

```
$('.btn-icon').on('click',function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('colorMe');
)};
```

How would I go about removing the class from a button that has been pressed class when a new button is pressed?

Just to reiterate when I click on get past the menu button and click on a sub menu button it turns white. I want to make that button turn black when another is pressed.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjrPxe?editors=1111

Comment: Kindly clarify more clearly?

Comment: @PraveenKumar when you go to the link click on one of the buttons...when you click on another both will be white instead of the first one changing back to black

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(".colorMe").removeClass("colorMe");`

Run before your existing toggleClass line.

Comment: `$(this)` is the object that had the event fire.  If you want to remove the class from a sibling (or some other element) you need to know how to target it.  In this case we know for sure that it has the `colorMe` class, so I simply wrote a selector to select all elements with the `colorMe` class and remove that class from them.  If clicking the same object again is supposed to remove the class as well, you'd have to write a filter to not re-add the `colorMe` class to `this` again after removing it.